# vbscript - returning object from array via function

Tags: asp-classic

I've been looking online for a way to make a vbscript function to return an object I created:

```
<%

dim myArray(5)
set myArray(5) = new MyClass

for i = 0 to 5
response.write("i :" & i & "<br/>")
set myArray(i) = new MyClass
myArray(i).MyText = "Number " & i
next

class MyClass

    public MyText

End class

function getMyClass(text)

    set getMyClass = new MyClass
    getMyClass.MyText = text

end function


    response.write(getmyclass("Here!").mytext & "<br/>")

function getMyArray(number)

    response.write("check: " & myArray(number).MyText & "<br/>")
    set getMyArray = new MyClass
    getMyArray = myArray(number)

end function

    response.write(getMyArray(1).mytext)

%>
```

This is the error I'm getting:

Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a01b6'

Object doesn't support this property or method

/carousel classes/funcarray.asp, line 32

And it refers to the function "getMyArray(number)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to recode this to make it work...

```vbs
<%

dim myArray(5), i

for i = 0 to 5
    response.write("i :" & i & "<br/>")
    set myArray(i) = new MyClass
    myArray(i).MyText = "Number " & i
next

class MyClass

    public MyText

End class

function getMyClass(text)
    dim rv
    set rv = new MyClass
    rv.MyText = text
    set getMyClass = rv
end function

response.write(getmyclass("Here!").mytext & "<br/>")

function getMyArray(number)
    response.write("check: " & myArray(number).MyText & "<br/>")
    set getMyArray = myArray(number)
end function

response.write(getMyArray(1).mytext)

%>
```

NOTES:

I removed the second line as it doesn't do what you think.

I found that the problem with your `getMyClass` function was that as soon as you `Set` the function name then the value is returned and no value will be passed to the `MyText` field.

The second function was nearly there and simply required the function name to be `Set` to one of the predefined array entries.